# Error in create back up in mysql through java program

Tags: java

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\mysql\\bin\\mysqldump -u root -pmypassword  Databasename -r C:/backup.sql");
```

I am using this code to create back up from my sql. but It creates the empty file in the path.Because it is waiting in the command prompt to get the password. How can i give password to it
            Using command prompt directly when i press enter after typing, it asks password.After giving password,It creates the backup.Give me any solution for this
                     Thanks in advance

Comment: @Arivu2020 any progress? did you solve your problem? If yes - mark an answer as accepted

Answer (score 2):

try the longer version

```
C:\mysql\bin\mysqldump -u root --password=mypassword Databasename -r C:/backup.sql
```

are you sure this password is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Leave a space between `-p` and `mypassword`, like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\mysql\\bin\\mysqldump -u root -p mypassword Databasename -r C:/backup.sql");
```

Parameters to mysql commands often take two forms: The short form is `-o value` (with a space between), the longer form is `--option=value` (no space). You can't mix 'n' match the syntax.